# Can I prevent DocuSign from asking recipients for their location?

Tags: docusignapi

Can I prevent DocuSign from asking recipients for their location, since it won't be relevant to the document they're signing?

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for answering, Max!

> If you have access to DocuSign's Signing Resource File in Branding, it can be disabled for all envelopes by setting the DocuSign_DisableLocationAwareness node to true (disabled). The default value is false (enabled). For more information, please see the DocuSign Signing Resource File Information Guide. For assistance in gaining access to this feature or for futher assistance, contact your DocuSign Account Manager.

http://community.docusign.com/t5/Sending-Options-and-Features/Why-does-DocuSign-want-to-know-my-location/td-p/4433

Answer (score 1):

Go to `about:config` (type it in the URL bar) and search for `geo.enabled`. double click it to set it to false and that should do the trick.

Taken from the Mozilla Firefox help docs:
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/ (last question on the page)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to prevent DocuSign from asking for location though. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Some more info on this - http://community.docusign.com/t5/Sending-Options-and-Features/Why-does-DocuSign-want-to-know-my-location/td-p/4433